# While using 3 stages in JavaFX, on closing third stage focus goes to second instead of first stage

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

I have 3 stages opened in JavaFX:

1. primary stage (say A)
2. stage opened from application menu (say B)
3. Window Dialog  opened from context menu on primary stage (say C).

After closing C window, focused should be moved to A window but foucs is moving to B window. It seems to be issue with JavaFX `stage.close()`.

This is the second window opened:

[image: Second window]

Third window opened. On click on cancel it goes back to second window:

[image: Third window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve this by changing the stage initModality from APPLICATION_MODAL to WINDOW_MODAL while creating the stage for child window.